# saving and removing weekly schedule in async storage react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, asyncstorage

I have a scenario in my project where i have to save weekly **schedule with start and end time**

**What i want**

> user can enter day schedule with start and end
>   time and can remove.

Also i have validation that if **user has already a day schedule he can't save another on same day before removing first one.**

What i've tried

> AsyncStorage multiset and multiget

but i haven't reached at my goals.

Please lemme know how can i save and get back schedule from **AsyncStorage** either using objects or associative array.

[image: UI pic]

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can only store Strings in AsyncStorage. You will need to stringify your Array/Object and parse back on retrieving.

Async Storage stores key and value pairs.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
```

```
async setSchedule(schedule){
   try{
     let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("schedule");
     if(value==null)
     {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("schedule",JSON.stringify(schedule));
        console.log("schedule Not there);
     }
     else{
        console.log("schedule aldready set");
     }
   }
   catch(er){
   }
}

async removeSchedule()
{
   await AsyncStorage.removeItem("schedule")
}

async getSchedule()
{
   let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("schedule")
   return JSON.parse(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the data as an object, and save it in async storage as a string using `JSON.stringify`

```
state = {
 schedule: [{ day: 'Monday', start: '9:00', end: '17:00'}]
}
```

save items as string

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('schedule', JSON.stringify(this.state.schedule));
```

Retrieve the items.

```
const items = await AsyncStorage.getItem('schedule');
const schedule = JSON.parse(items);
```

[DEMO](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/save-flatlist-items-in-a-different-flatlist)

Answer (score 0):

Save the data as an object, and save it async storage as a string using JSON.stringify

```
state = {
 schedule: [{ day: 'Monday', start: '9:00', end: '17:00'}]
}
```

Save items as string